# Checked radio button sends AJAX call and radio button appends

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web-services, web

I'm just trying to upon checking a radio button send AJAX call and radio button append using JavaScript.

I've tried several things but have not been able to get this right:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.split(',').length; i++) {
    $('#radio_append').append('<input name="suggested_dates" id="suggested_dates'+count+'" value="' + response.split(',')[i] + '" class="styled chal_bhi_radio" type="radio" /><label for="suggested_dates'+count+'">' + response.split(',')[i] + '</label> <br> ')
    count++;
}
```

After append this radio button, there are four radio button on click on any one radio button send this AJAX call.

I'm trying several things but didn't work.

On select any checkbox it didn't show alert box. These radio button append from JavaScript.

[image]

```js
$(".chal_bhi_radio").on('change', function() {
      alert("HI");
      var date_al = $(".chal_bhi_radio:checked").val();
      $.post("<?php echo $site_root;?>common/service.php?j=4", {
          date_select: date_al
        },
        function(response) {
          if (response != '') {
            per_data = $.parseJSON(response);
            if (per_data != 0) {
              $("#price_special_append").html("");
              add_basic = per_data;
              $("#price_special_append").append(" € " + add_basic + " ")
            }
          }
        });
```

Comment: it's not duplicated, check the code snips thanks

Comment: It is. Especially if you said "it worked for me" to the answer below

Comment: believe me it's work for me and, didn't copy from provided link..

Comment: That is not the point - the principle is identical

Answer (score 2):

You should use event delegation as the newly appended elements won't have an event listener attached to them:

Note the event handler is attached to the NEAREST static element and we are using click. The value can ONLY come from this radio so no need to scan the dom for checked radios unless you have more sets of them

```
$('#radio_append').on("click", ".chal_bhi_radio",function(){
  alert("HI");
  var date_al = $(this).val();
});
```

**Event delegation** won't attach the event listeners directly to the `.chal_bhi_radio`. But instead, it will attach them to another element (here `document`). So when ever that element is clicked it will check if the target element match the selector (second argument `".chal_bhi_radio"`). Read more about event delegation.

Comment: thanks dear its work for me...

Comment: why user marked my question as [duplicate] ???

Comment: @MuhammadAwaisZulifqar See the link, you'll understand why.